# Graphical SQL client

Tags: windows, gui, sql

I have always used MySQL (or MariaDB, which is essentially the same thing) from the native command-line interface, which works fine. But I've recently started needing simultaneous access to both MySQL and Redshift at work (on Windows 10), and someone suggested I use [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/), a GUI for simultaneous multiple connections in multiple SQL flavors. I've started using it, and it has opened my eyes to the wonders of GUI. I can look at a list of columns, indices, or the like, without opening a new command-line window or needing to thereafter scroll back several pages! The wonders of modern technology, I tell you.

But DBeaver has one significant drawback that is slowly driving me nuts. Every time I need to export the full result set of a query to CSV or the like, I should be able to right-click, select "Export From Query", and be done. Instead, "Export From Query" is generally greyed out. Occasionally it's not, and I manage to get my result set exported, but it seems to depend on… I don't know what. Phase of the moon, maybe?

So I'm looking for an alternative. Specifically, I would like the alternative to:

- run on Windows 10 (required)
- be free ([like beer](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre)) (very preferable)
- be free (like beer) or cheap (e.g., donationware) (required)
- allow access to MySQL and Redshift on different servers (required)
- not require me to type a password each time I connect (preferable)
- allow export to CSV (or tab- or pipe-delimited or the like) (required)
- allow queries to combine two SQL flavors on two servers, as e.g. `where foo in({server_alias: query})` (very preferable)
- highlight syntax (preferable)
- … I'm new enough to SQL GUIs that I don't even know what additional features to look for

Comment: Since DBeaver  is perfect except for the "phase of the moon" issue, did you contact the author, or post on their forum?

Comment: @Mawg not perfect except for that: it also doesn't "allow queries to combine two SQL flavors on two servers", which I list as "very preferable".

Comment: Perhaps you cold request them to add a new feature? In my experience, s/w developers (of which I am one), are keen to add new features which are request by users.  Although, to be honest, I doubt that you will ever find anything to combine queries as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend checking out [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). It's free and runs on Windows 10. It'll let you connect to multiple DBs and save your login passwords among other things.

Comment: That was the one that immediately came up for me too. I have used it somewhat in the past (not enough to write a decent recommendation), but I know it has been maintained and extended for many years now.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how which of the other features I mentioned it has?

Comment: Please add a check/cross for each bullet requirement. Also, a screenshot would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As much as I do like Mysql Workbench, I have come to prefer [HeidiSql](http://www.heidisql.com/)
Features

> ```
> Free for everyone, OpenSource since 9 years of active development.
> Connect to multiple servers in one window
> Connect to servers via commandline
> Connect via SSH tunnel, or pass SSL settings
> Create and edit tables, views, stored routines, triggers and scheduled events.
> Generate nice SQL-exports, compress these afterwards, or put them on the clipboard.
> Export from one server/database directly to another server/database
> Manage user-privileges
> Import text-files
> Export table rows as CSV, HTML, XML, SQL, LaTeX, Wiki Markup and PHP Array
> Browse and edit table-data using a comfortable grid
> Bulk edit tables (move to db, change engine, collation etc.)
> Batch-insert ascii or binary files into tables
> Write queries with customizable syntax-highlighting and code-completion
> Pretty reformat disordered SQL
> Monitor and kill client-processes
> Find specific text in all tables of all databases of one server
> Optimize and repair tables in a batch manner
> Launch a parallel mysql.exe command line window using your current connection settings
> And much more
> ```

Obligatory screenshot:
[image]

If you run a local server (maybe [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) under Windows?), then you probably know [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/); I have come to prefer the single PHP file, easy to switch between databse servers [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) ([Why is Adminer better than phpMyAdmin?](https://www.adminer.org/en/phpmyadmin/))

> ```
> Connect to a database server with username and password
> Select an existing database or create a new one
> List fields, indexes, foreign keys and triggers of table
> Change name, engine, collation, auto_increment and comment of table
> Alter name, type, collation, comment and default values of columns
> Add and drop tables and columns
> Create, alter, drop and search by indexes including fulltext
> Create, alter, drop and link lists by foreign keys
> Create, alter, drop and select from views
> Create, alter, drop and call stored procedures and functions
> Create, alter and drop triggers
> List data in tables with search, aggregate, sort and limit results
> Insert new records, update and delete the existing ones
> Supports all data types, blobs through file transfer
> Execute any SQL command from a text field or a file
> Export table structure, data, views, routines, databases to SQL or CSV
> Print database schema connected by foreign keys
> Show processes and kill them
> Display users and rights and change them
> Display variables with links to documentation
> Manage events and table partitions (MySQL 5.1)
> Schemas, sequences, user types (PostgreSQL)
> Extensive customization options
> ```

---

[Update] Here's a shot my adminer login, with a choice of two remembered sites. I have chosen not to even attempt to save passwords, on security grounds and won't try it for you for that reason. Please, give it a try & let us know.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I don't run a local server and am not sure what PHP has to do with SQL. In any event, do you know how this program does on the other criteria I list, e.g. "allow queries to combine two SQL flavors on two servers" and "not require me to type a password each time I connect" and "run on Windows 10"?

Comment: You need a server for the PHP interpreter. Upload Adminer to any server over which you have control, or, XAMPP  is a simple install & forget. To be honest, I doubt that you will find anything to combine queries as you wish.  I do use Windows 10. If you only use one server, you can “remember” settings, and not have to type the password. I am unsure if you can enter passwords for multiple setups and then select form a drop down list (there is a drop down list of previous sessions). However, since Adminer runs in the browser, you should be able to have the browser remember passwords for you.